# RPi3 captive portal iptables issues

Tags: access-point

I've been spending the last week or so learning how to program the Rpi3, and have so far had success.  This is where I'm stuck at. I've set up an access point (here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md), installed a webserver (like this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md) and have made a basic website using the GPIOs and following this: https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-and-intuitive-web-interface-for-your-Raspbe/

I've been saving images so I can always reset to a fresh start.  Starting from a blank slate, I setup the access point, and installed the webserver (apache/php).  I now want to make a captive portal (like this: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-captive-portal/)

Everything seems to work until I try to start nodogsplash, I get the "iptables no chain/target/match" over and over when I try to start nodogsplash.

What do I do?  I've tried changing the settings within the iptables (including reseting to defaults) but I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: when you followed the instructions in the last link - did you follow instructions for raspbian stretch? Did you get an errors in any of the steps along the way?

Comment: this may be a consequence of a kernel module that is not available or hasn't been loaded.  Something in your configuration isn't fit for nodogsplash.  Can you find out what the iptable commands are that generates those errors?   Anything in /var/log  (check the most recently changed files).

Comment: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash says you need to install a number of extra kernel modules.